# Unity3D: How to go Back or Forward in Array list

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a gameObject with an ID, the gameObjects are spawned by giving initial ID: 1 , then any after spawned will be +1 so next is ID: 2.

I have two buttons that check current gameObjects ID#, BackOneButton (-1) and PlusOneButton (+1).

Currently it works but only if the array of gameObjects have IDs in order like for example [gameObject-ID:1], [gameObject-ID:2], [gameObject-ID:3]

But since you can self destruct a certain gameObject, here is where the error is --->

Now the array is not in order for example [gameObject-ID:1], [gameObject-ID:3], [gameObject-ID:4]. So if I'm currently in [gameObject-ID:3] and I use the BackOneButton and looks for ID: 2 it won't find it BUT there is ID:1. That's my error, I can't seem to figure out how to handle this.

Basically, How do I handle missing increments and skip over the missing?

Left Button (MinusOneButton)

```c#
void ButtonAction_LeftMinusOne()
{
    //  Get list of all gameObjects and -1 current to switch
    string objName = manager.currentObjectTransform.name;
    string[] splitArray = objName.Split('_');
    string idObjNumber = splitArray[1];
    switch (idObjNumber)
    {
        case "0":
            //  not supposed to be ID: 0
            break;

        case "1":
            //  nothing to go back to, this is ID: 1
            break;

        default:

            //  currently in (ID: 2 & Up) second object
            int currentID = int.Parse(idObjNumber);
            string idBackOne = (currentID - 1).ToString();
            GameObject[] allObjInFull = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Object");

            if (allObjInFull.Length >= 2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < allObjInFull.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (allObjInFull[i].transform.name.Contains(idBackOne))
                    {
                        //  Set Camera
                        camera.transform.parent = allObjInFull[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1);
                        camera.transform.position = allObjInFull[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).position;
                        camera.transform.rotation = allObjInFull[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).rotation;
                    }
                }
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Right Button (PlusOneButton)

```c#
void ButtonAction_RightPlusOne()
{
    //  Get list of all objects and +1 current to switch
    string objName = manager.currentObjectTransform.name;
    string[] splitArray = objName.Split('_');
    string idObjNumber = splitArray[1];
    switch (idObjNumber)
    {
        case "0":
            //  not supposed to be ID: 0
            break;

        default:

            //  currently in (ID: 1 & Up) object
            int currentID = int.Parse(idObjNumber);
            string idPlusOne = (currentID + 1).ToString();
            GameObject[] allObjInFull = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Object");

            if (allObjInFull.Length >= 2)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < allObjInFull.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (allObjInFull[i].transform.name.Contains(idPlusOne))
                    {
                        //  Set Camera
                        camera.transform.parent = allObjInFull[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1);
                        camera.transform.position = allObjInFull[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).position;
                        camera.transform.rotation = allObjInFull[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(1).rotation;
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be way better (especially regarding maintenance) and more efficient to have a central manager class with a `List<GameObject>` where you simply `Add` and `Remove` items dynamically. (Since you already seem to have one in `manager` I would rather extend that one)

```c#
public static class ObjectsManager
{
    // If you are not concerned about
    // capsulation you could ofcourse make this public as well
    // but I thought this is cleaner
    private static List<GameObject> objects;

    // Read-only property
    public static int Count
    {
        get
        {
            Initialize();

            return objects.Count;
        }
    }

    // initialize the list once
    // I first had this in e.g. Awake
    // but now you can easily use this in multiple scenes
    public static void Initialize(bool force reinitialize = false)
    {
        if(objects != null && ! reinitialize) return;

        objects = FindObjectsWithTag("Object").ToList();
    }

    public static void Add(GameObject newObject)
    {
        Initialize();
        if(objects.Contains(newObject) return;

        objects.Add(newObject);
    }

    public static void Destroy(GameObject toDestroy)
    {
        Initialize();
        if(objects.Contains(toDestroy)
        {
            objects.Remove(toDestroy);
        }

        Object.Destroy(toDestroy);
    }

    public static int IndexOf(GameObject obj)
    {
        Initialize();
        return objects.IndexOf(obj);
    }

    public static GameObject GetByIndex(int index)
    {
        Initialize();

        // Use modulo to wrap around the index in case 
        // +1 or -1 exceeds the list ends
        // in your case you might not need it
        // but I decided to add it to be more flexible
        var nextIndex = (index + 1) % objects.Count;

        return objects[index];
    }
}
```

Everytime you Instantiate a new object make sure to also call

```c#
ObjectsManager.Add(newObject);
```

and everytime where you destroy an object rather use

```c#
ObjectsManager.Destroy(objectToDestroy);
```

so it is also removed from the list first.

Then you can easily use

```c#
var currentIndex = ObjectsManager.IndexOf(certainObject);
```

to get the current index of an object and simply move through the index (`+1`, `-1`)

```c#
var nextObject = ObjectsManager.GetByIndex(currentIndex + 1);

var lastObject = Objects manager.GetByIndex(currentIndex - 1);
```

In case you switch the scene you have reinitialize the list once in order to get rid of null references

```c#
ObjectsManager.Initialize(true);
```

---

In your example code you would e.g. use something like

```c#
void ButtonAction_LeftMinusOne()
{
    GameObject currentObject = manager.currentObjectTransform.gameObject;
    int currentIndex = ObjectsManager.IndexOf(currentObject);

    if(currentIndex < 0)
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Object {0} is not in list!", currentObject.name);
        return;
    }

    if(currentIndex == 0)
    {
        // nothing to do go back to
        // Except you want wrap around then simply remove this check
        Debug.Log("Already is first object in list", this);
        return;
    }

    GameObject newObject = ObjectsManager.GetByIndex(currentIndex - 1);

    Transform childOfNewObject = newObject.GetChild(0).GetChild(1);

    //  Set Camera
    // Using simply SetParent with parameter worldPositionStays=false
    // reduces it to one single call
    camera.transform.SetParent( childOfNewObject, false);
}
```

And accordingly

```c#
void ButtonAction_RightPlusOne()
{
    GameObject currentObject = manager.currentObjectTransform.gameObject;
    int currentIndex = ObjectsManager.IndexOf(currentObject);

    if(currentIndex < 0)
    {
        Debug.LogErrorFormat(this, "Object {0} is not in list!", currentObject.name);
        return;
    }

    if(currentIndex == ObjectsManager.Count - 1)
    {
        // nothing to do go forward to
        // Except you want wrap around then simply remove this check
        Debug.Log("Already is last object in list", this);
        return;
    }

    GameObject newObject = ObjectsManager.GetByIndex(currentIndex + 1);

    Transform childOfNewObject = newObject.GetChild(0).GetChild(1);

    //  Set Camera
    // Using simply SetParent with parameter worldPositionStays=false
    // reduces it to one single call
    camera.transform.SetParent( childOfNewObject, false);
}
```

Comment: so you're grabbing all the gameObjects with tag "Object' and then move up or down that list? therefore fixing the problem if my list is missing an ID, for example, so if I'm in 3 and 2 was destroyed, I can go back to 1 from 3 skipping 2. right?

Comment: Yep should do that. I'm not going by name but index in the List